# xml_data to pass PHP variables

Tags: php, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, opencart, sms-gateway

I have integrated SMS Gateway in my Opencart CMS

It uses the following SYNTAX

```
    $xml_data ='<?xml version="1.0"?><smslist><sms><user>username</user
<password>112131</password><message>Your order # {$order_id} has been successfully received. Thank you for placing an Order at mystore.com</message><mobiles>9898000000</mobiles><senderid>Sherif</senderid><cdmasenderid>00201009546310</cdmasenderid><accountusagetypeid>1</accountusagetypeid></sms></smslist>';  

$URL = "http://mainadmin.dove-sms.com/sendsms.jsp?"; 

            $ch = curl_init($URL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

Please make note that I have not used my personal credentials and this is just a syntax. I have tested the code and it works absolutely fine using my credentials

Now, What I want is it should load the order number, instead it shows the text `{$order_id}` in my message!

Moreover I want the text to be sent to the user who has logged-in in my stored by fetching the `$telephone` variable

Please help and thanks in advance

File in which this code is included: `catalog/controller/checkout/sucess.php`

Opencart version: 1.5.6

Find the Screenshot of the message I have Received [here](http://postimg.org/image/dh1aza4xx/)

Comment: Maybe `order # '. $order_id .' has`?

Comment: @OfirBaruch you just beat me :)

Comment: @OfirBaruch: it gives an error Notice: Undefined variable: order_id in /home/arcanmyn/public_html/arcjewels.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_checkout_success.php on line 119

Comment: Now that's a different error ;)
From where do you get the `order_id` value?

Comment: According to the git: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php#L6
You should use `$this->session->data['order_id']`

Comment: its inside 'catalog/controller/account/order.php'

Comment: how do I implement it?

Comment: the git what you shared is already implemented in my success.php file

Comment: did the changes according to the git you sent! Now receiving error as follows 'code'Notice: Error: Could not load model account/activity! in /home/arcanmyn/public_html/arcjewels.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 48

Comment: @JigarAshar check my answer, don't forget to delete the contents of *vqcache* folder after you are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Now, What I want is it should load the order number, instead it shows the text {$order_id} in my message!**

That's because you are using a single quoted string for the variable `$xml_data`, single quoted strings in PHP display things **as is** (variables won't be substituted with their values, they will be treated as text), to solve this issue, use a double quoted string instead ([according to the PHP manual](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single))

> **Moreover I want the text to be sent to the user who has logged-in in my stored by fetching the $telephone variable**

simply `$telephone = $this->customer->getTelephone()`, now you just need to put the variable `$telephone` in the correct tag in `$xml_data`

#### Edit

I have read the post comments and noticed that you get an error that says `$order_id` is not defined, to solve that, use `$this->session->data['order_id']` instead of `$order_id` and place your SMS code in the beginning of the 
`if (isset($this->session->data['order_id']))` code block like that (to use the value of order id before it's erased from session):

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
    $xml_data ="<?xml version="1.0"?><smslist><sms><user>username</user
<password>112131</password><message>Your order # {$this->session->data['order_id']} has been successfully received. Thank you for placing an Order at mystore.com</message><mobiles>9898000000</mobiles><senderid>Sherif</senderid><cdmasenderid>00201009546310</cdmasenderid><accountusagetypeid>1</accountusagetypeid></sms></smslist>";  
    $URL = "http://mainadmin.dove-sms.com/sendsms.jsp?"; 
    $ch = curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // here put the rest of the code
    $this->cart->clear();
    // ...
}
```

**Finally**, delete cotenets of the the folder *vqcache*

Comment: i did the changes as described by you! but I receive the following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/arcanmyn/public_html/arcjewels.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_checkout_success.php on line 8

Comment: although i deleted the contents of vqcache, they end to come up again on page load and refresh!

Comment: @JigarAshar yes they will be generated again, you delete them only once to ensure that the new modification you have done will be considered in the new cache files

Comment: no i still receive the same error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/arcanmyn/public_html/arcjewels.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_checkout_success.php on line 8

Comment: it seems that these code updates conflict with an extension you are using in the checkout page, what is this extension? can you post it here? (the XML file)

Comment: there are many extensions used see screenshot [link](http://s1.postimg.org/69oe2zia7/Untitled2.png)

Comment: these are essential for website and over 50% of them are already include in the custom theme I am using

Comment: don't worry, we won't remove them  :D, I just need to determine which extension makes the conflict, can you post another screenshot of the other extensions?

Comment: there are many checkout extensions, such a situation is very error prone, I suggest  adding the SMS code block in another file, what about the model function that saves order details and sends an email to the user? open the file `<OC_ROOT>/catalog/model/checkout/order.php` and search for `public function confirm`, add your codeblock there right before the ending of the function (directly before the last `}`) and give me feedback, you can use the variable `$order_id` directly there (no need to $this->session->....)

Comment: OMG! You are awesome! just nailed it right and perfect! Can I buy you a cup of coffee? I have some 2-3 other issues, can I have you on skype? PM you skype id

Comment: glad for you ;)  I don't mind providing further help but I have work to do :) so it's better to post your other issues here on SO and either me or the guys will always be here to help

Comment: just one last thing! I want to do same with telephone! send sms to the customer on his telephone!<br>I added <mobiles>'. $telephone .'</mobiles> but it does not send SMS to the customer who's mobile number was added

Comment: the customer registered telephone (on his account) `$telephone = $this->customer->getTelephone()` , the customer telephone in the order can be retrieved from the order details object, luckily it's already defined there in the function so just use `$telephone = $order_info['telephone']`,